# IntelliJ Idea is not working with Servlet but working with JSP pages

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to develop a webapplication (with Jsp & Servlets) and deploy in tomcat. After successfully deployed, I can access only JSP pages but not Servlets. I have tried in both the ways : given a link with reference to the (Relative and absolute) pah of the Servlet and given the URL directly in the browser address bar. Please help me out.

index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Welcome</h2>
    Click <a href="ServletDemo_01">here</a> to ServletDemo_01.<br><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

ServletDemo_01.java

```
package com.ignite.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet(name = "ServletDemo_01")
public class ServletDemo_01 extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello");
        out.close();

    }
}
```

Note : I didn't update any thing in the default web.xml, since I am using WebServlet annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated annotation as below, then it's solved.

```
@javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet(name = "ServletDemo_01", urlPatterns = "/ServletDemo_01")
```